# Segmentation Fault about assembly code of manipulating global array

Tags: arrays, pointers, assembly

I am working on a project about get input character string like
0011001101100110 ( 8 bits, 16 bits, 32 bits....)
store each 8 bits value into an array byte

However, I have just encountered segmentation fault of my code.
Does the void function and no function parameter need push step?

```
    laser.asm

    section .data
    message: times 128 db 0 

    section .text
    USE32

    global _start
    _start:
          push ebp
          mov esp, ebp
          call decode_message
          call print_message

          mov ebx, 0
          mov eax, 1
          int 80h

     print_character:

          push ebp
          mov ebp, esp
          push ebx

          mov eax, 4
          mov ebx, 1
          lea ecx, [ebp+8]
          mov edx, 1
          int 0x80

          pop ebx
          leave
          ret

     read_character:

          push ebp
          mov ebp, esp
          sub esp, 4
          push ebx

          mov eax, 3
          mov ebx, 0
          lea ecx, [ebp-4]
          mov edx, 1
          int 0x80

          mov eax, [ebp-4]
          pop ebx
          add esp, 4
          leave
          ret

     get_bit:
          push ebp
          mov ebp, esp
          call read_character
          cmp eax, 48
          je zero

          cmp eax, 49
          je one

          zero:
          mov eax, 0
          leave
          ret
          one:
          mov eax, 1
          leave
          ret

     get_byte:
         push ebp
         mov ebp, esp
         mov ebx, 8
         cmp ebx, 0
         mov ecx, eax
         jge end

         call get_bit
         cmp eax, 0
         je b_zero

         cmp eax, 1
         je b_one

         b_zero:
         shl ecx, 1 
         jmp end

         b_one:
         shl ecx, 1
         or ecx, 1
         jmp end    

         end:
         mov eax, ecx
         leave
         ret

     decode_message:
         push ebp
         mov ebp, esp
         sub esp, 0x128
         mov DWORD [ebp-0x4], 0x0;
         call get_byte
         jmp d_test

         d_loop:
         mov ebx, DWORD [ebp-0x4];
         mov edx, eax
         mov DWORD [ebx*4+0x804a040], edx;
         add DWORD [ebp-0x4], 0x1;  
         call get_byte

         d_test:
         cmp eax, 0
         jne d_loop
         leave
         ret

     print_message:
         push ebp
         mov ebp, esp
         sub esp, 0x128
         mov DWORD [ebp-0x4], 0x0;
         jmp p_test

         p_loop:
         mov ebx, DWORD [ebp-0x4];
         mov eax, DWORD [ebx*4+0x804a040];
         push eax
         call print_character
         add esp, 4
         add DWORD [ebp-0x4], 0x1;

         p_test:
         cmp eax, 0
         jne p_loop
         leave
         ret
```

Comment: `mov esp, ebp` in `_start` is reversed. You should step through in a debugger (like _GDB_)

Comment: This also looks suspicious `mov DWORD [ebx*4+0x804a040], edx;` . where did you get the hard coded value `0x804a040`? You use it in a couple places. It may not even be memory that you access

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> _start:
>     push ebp
>     mov esp, ebp
>     call decode_message
> ```

The `mov esp, ebp` instruction needs to be `mov ebp, esp`.

---

> ```
> get_byte:
>     push ebp
>     mov ebp, esp
>     mov ebx, 8
>     cmp ebx, 0
>     mov ecx, eax
>     jge end
> ```

This procedure will always jump to the *end* label! You moved a value of 8 in the `EBX` register and then compared it to 0. This always sets the *greater* condition. Your code will thus never `call get_bit` or `call read_character`.
That way the `EAX` register doesn't change overtime, and since the parent procedure *decode_message* only loops if `EAX` is non-zero, your program could silently do nothing at all (if you are lucky). But as it stands you got 2 more problems that will eventually trigger the segmentation error:

- You didn't setup the `EAX` before calling the *decode_message* procedure. It's most probably non-zero.
- You used some very suspicious memory offsets (0x804a040).